# Plotting polylines in Google Map API using SPINNER

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio

How to plot polylines using the spinner in **Android Studio** (Google MAP API)? This is how it works, whenever the user clicks the button in the spinner, it'll plot the polyline in the google map. This is the last thing we need, please help us. I can't find an answer to plot the lines using the time spinner.

```html
package com.example.admin.mobiletrafficanalyzer2;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class challmanila extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    Spinner spinner;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_challmanila);


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("12:00AM - 1:00AM");
        list.add("1:01AM - 2:00AM");
        list.add("2:01AM - 3:30AM");
        list.add("3:31AM - 4:30AM");
        list.add("4:31AM - 5:30AM");
        list.add("5:31AM - 6:00AM");
        list.add("6:01AM - 6:15AM");
        list.add("6:16AM - 10:00AM");
        list.add("10:01AM - 12:00PM");
        list.add("12:01PM - 2:30PM");
        list.add("2:31PM - 6:00PM");
        list.add("6:01PM - 9PM");
        list.add("9:01PM - 10:30PM");
        list.add("10:31PM - 12:59PM");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                spinner.setSelection(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng challmanila = new LatLng(14.589892, 120.981580);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(challmanila).title("Marker in City Hall Manila"));
        float zoomLevel = 16.0f;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(challmanila, zoomLevel=16.0f));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just adding polyline to map whenever item is selected on the spinner?

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
  if(mMap == null) return;

  Polyline polyline1 = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
          .clickable(true)
          .add(
                  new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                  new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                  new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                  new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                  new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                  new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309)));
}
```

You might write some code for case when mMap = null which means that map was not loaded yet or tehre was error. So in this case you would like to store polylineOptions somewhere and display it whenever map is ready.